# Why won't my if-else statement work using OR ( | | )?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

When I run the program, the console gives me an error that "Sunday" (and "Saturday", based on the user input) does not exist. I have tried many combinations in the if statement with the parentheses and nothing worked.

```
var day = prompt("Enter a day of the week.");
console.log("Day is: " + day);
//if user input is equal to Sunday OR user input is equal to Saturday,
if (getText(day) == "Sunday" || getText(day) == "Saturday") {
  console.log("It's the weekend!");
} else {
  console.log("Can't wait for the weekend to get here.");
}
```

Comment: You're missing a language tag.  This looks like Javascript to me.  I have a feeling that string equality uses the `===` operator in Javascript, not `==` (which only tests if it's the same underlying object).

Comment: Where is your getText function? Uncaught ReferenceError: getText is not defined.

Comment: When asking a question about code, it's important to add a tag for the specific language being used. Please [edit] your question to do so, so that we can try to help. Thanks.

Comment: In JavaScript == tests equality, but === tests for an exact match including data type. Most of the time == is used. If you compare an integer 1 to a string "1" == will evaluate to true.

Comment: @paddy: You're mixing it up with other languages; JS `===`/`==` is not analogous to Python `==`/`is`. `==` is type-coercing equality, `===` is type-strict equality. Either one would work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `getText` and it will work correctly:

```js
var day = prompt('Enter a day of the week.');
console.log('Day is: ' + day);
if (day == 'Sunday' || day == 'Saturday') {
  console.log("It's the weekend!");
} else {
  console.log("Can't wait for the weekend to get here.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `prompt()` function always returns a `string` if user clicks "OK" or `null` if user clicks "Cancel". In your case, as long as you enter something and click "Ok", `day` will be a string which could be `"Sunday"` or `"Saturday"`.

However, if you want to treat uppercase and lowercase letters as equal, for example `"sunday"` is equipvalent to `"Sunday"`, you should use either the `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` method to make sure both strings are either all lowercase or all uppercase. Something like below:

```
var day = prompt("Enter a day of the week.");
console.log("Day is: " + day);
//if user input is equal to Sunday OR user input is equal to Saturday,
if (day.toLowerCase() == "sunday" || day.toLowerCase() == "saturday") {
  console.log("It's the weekend!");
} else {
  console.log("Can't wait for the weekend to get here.");
}
```